# New Google Realtime Document timing issue

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am creating a new in-memory realtime document from a large JSON:

```
var newDoc = gapi.drive.realtime.loadFromJson(jsonData);
```

Then saving that new document to a newly created drive file:

```
newDoc.saveAs(file.id);
```

I also monitor "isSaving" on the document:

```
newDoc.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.DOCUMENT_SAVE_STATE_CHANGED, onSaveStateChange);

function onSaveStateChange(e) {
    blah...
}
```

The problem is that when, according to the API, the document is apparently no longer saving, it IS in fact still uploading (as checked by Resource Monitor), and if I try to open that document during that time, I get unpredictable results.

This appears to be a realtime bug with the setting of isSaving, or the triggering of DOCUMENT_SAVE_STATE_CHANGED.

I badly need a way to determine when the new file is ACTUALLY available for use. A hack of some sort, or having to make an extra call would be fine... but as is, putting in any arbitrarily long delay won't account for a slow or intermittent network.

Comment: We are looking into this.

Comment: I've started checking SaveDelay as well... it appears that when that drops to zero, the upload is complete. Any idea if that's reliable?

Comment: @CherylSimon Should have tagged you in that last comment-question.

Comment: @CherylSimon Any updates?